# Adding Bar Button Item

Tags: objective-c, view, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

**problem**

I cannot for the life of me get it to show.

Here's the implementation of the nav bar

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[_navBar setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:_navBar];
```

_navBar is a `UINavigationBar` property.

Here's where I add the button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(flipView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

However, nothing shows. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.navigationItem` is read automatically by a parent UINavigationController. But you don't have one.

Thus, you have two choices:

- Instead of a loose nav bar that you create and put into the interface yourself (as you are doing in your first code), be the child of a UINavigationController. Now setting `self.navigationItem` will work.
- Or, create a navigation item, configure it, and push it *manually* onto your loose nav bar. Your code will then have this structure:

  ```
  UINavigationItem* ni = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:// ...];
  UIBarButtonItem* b = // ...;
  ni.rightBarButtonItem = b;
  _navbar.items = @[ni];
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought this may be the outcome.

Comment: Added a little code to show you how the second approach works.